# Hints for start developing java application for storing and searching models and products

Tags: java

I want to start developing an application for storing in a database some products with a photo and do researches among them.

I have experience in Android programming, so also Java, and a little bit on GWT and App Engine...

I could write the application with GWT and App Engine but I must write an offline application.

How can I leverage my background to be more productive writing the application? Are there some shortcuts, environments, etcetera, to write these kinds of "standard application" in Java?

Thanks

Marco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetBeans has a pretty cool [Swing GUI builder](http://netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html) that can save you a lot of time.

For SQlite just use a JDBC driver like [this one](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/).

You probably shouldn't store images in the database itself, just the metadata (i.e. what you want to be able to search on), plus a reference to the image location in the filesystem (e.g. images/1234.jpg)

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look to netbeans and the gui builder. Thanks also for all others responses. For the database there is also SQLite? I don't want a server and I already know sqlite. Any hint for the images (but I think i can figure it out with a so large set of API)?

Comment: Updated my answer with some more suggestions that hopefully address your comment.

Answer (score 0):

The standard Java desktop application environment is Swing. Check the tutorials and start learning Swing.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an sqlite database of products using sqlite database browser and then use android to make that into a searchable list. I can provide some code for that if you wish

Comment: Oops I read wrong. Thought this was an android app. However the same principle would apply to a desktop java app. Definitely +1 on the Netbeans. I absolutely love it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely understand your question but I assume that, you are trying to develop a stand alone desktop application for managing photos. Given that you have a background in java, have you explored extending an existing application like the one using an [Eclipse Plugin](http://jaxenter.com/manage-your-photographs-with-eclipse-plugin-11604.html) and add your functionality on top of it, only if you must have an offline application. Personally, I would not create a standalone app for this. I would rather develop a web application using GWT or some other ajax framework for storing product images.

Comment: The funny thing it's that I've already done this web application, but the user don't want the data into the cloud. (I have already explained that the data are safer in the cloud but without results...)